# Как добавить в div несколько div'ов?

Tags: javascript

Приветствую!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить в див несколько дивов через перебор.
У меня есть 9 квадратов, в них я пытаюсь добавить 9 пустых дивов, но добавляется только по одному диву в каждый квадрат.
Вот мой код:

```
var squere = document.body.getElementsByClassName("squere");
for( var i = 0; i < squere.length; i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
squere[i].appendChild(div);
}
```

Буду очень признателен за помощь.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для каждого элемента `div.squere` действие создания дочернего элемента нужно повторить девять раз:

```
var squere = document.body.getElementsByClassName("squere");
for(var i = 0; i < squere.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    squere[i].appendChild(div);
  }
}
```